git rebase does not merge changes automatically
I have to rebase my topic branch from master.
There are some file with no conflicts; the rebase process, as I understood, should automatically merge changes without conflicts.
$ git checkout topic
$ git rebase origin/master
[...]

Git found conflicts on file like this one.
  var1: !vault |-
    $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
    36366663383735656435613639363261613264396363396236333639336234616165316530303262
    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    30396464336232356632326432333362633033343634643330316466343363326264326531383135
    3739396564656239330a366337336165313638666464336233393064316261653831363431653538
    3438
  var1: !vault |-
    $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
    37626162663262313063343861333663333231613934636137383633333733666439643337383163
    3463663631316435633037323166353335646362373439630a336431383538353931663065323461
    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    6631613836653731650a356237613264613637396339313166376565383937633862393632306437
    3735
  var3: !vault |-
    $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
    36313361666163386465376332633832303236343432663230626562316237333436303237353330
    3931366463623466636161346461363862643963363762610a383462386532383939363264383562
    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    3937313161663164370a656330323764396637376139613261623566643464636336326163666530
    6335
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
  var4: !vault |-
    $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
    62316234626263393665326432653865363564373930393934303361643735356466396666616135
    3137333262346135323566363264373333323231393665610a326239646535646265383235616639
    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    6330363266303565650a643134353865336635643035663362313836366364613938643265343337
    3863
>>>>>>> ec83581 (foobar comment)

Why git does not automatically merge this change? There are no conflicts!

if you want to view the real cause of the conflict: run git mergetool, or use git checkout --conflict=diff3. By default, git writes a file on disk using --conflict=merge, which is more compact, but does not display the text that was in the "base" version of the file.

Without knowing what the version of the merge-base looks like, I don't think we can say "there are no conflicts". Maybe someone deleted var4 on master? Or, is this a new file that was added on both branches separately but var4 was also added on your branch? Either of those would be a conflict.

Sometimes you can have line ending changes (ie. LF to CRLF). Typically git shows it as changed, but there's no difference from looking at the diff
